# C# Passing arguments to Sysinternals Autologon.exe

Tags: c#, autologin

I am trying to pass arguments to the SysInteranls Autologon.exe file, and am unable to do so.
This is the C# Code that I am using:

```
string usr = usrTextBox.Text.ToString();
                string auto = autologon;
                string domain = STORES;
                string pass = password;
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.FileName = "Autologon.exe";
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.Arguments = usr + domain + pass;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
```

It works if I set the startInfo.Arguments = "USER DOMAIN PASSWORD"; 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Todd

Comment: Why do you say you are unable to do so?  Are you seeing an error? If so, what?

Comment: Did you verify that the `usr`, `domain` and `pass` are correctly formatted?

Comment: Hey, for future AutoLogon folks: You can auto-accept that EULA dialog that pops up by adding "/accepteula" in front of the 3 parameters. It's great for distributing this in an installer.

Answer (score 5):

As per your last statement, You need a space in between them.

```
startInfo.Arguments = usr + " " + domain + " " + pass;
```

To keep the code cleaner, use the [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) method.

```
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", usr, domain, pass);
```

Comment: also ensure that au '-' (dashes) have a space in front of them. Have a look at `startInfo.Arguments` in a debugger to make sure the spaces are there.